# AWS Lambda serverless app (docker) markedly slower than local docker

Tags: .net, docker, aws-lambda, lucene, lucene.net

I am hosting a serverless docker app in AWS Lambda this is a .net 8 (however 6 and 7 and even beanstalk behaved the same). The app is .net lucene (4.8 which is in beta) search (index is quite small 140MB and is bundled with the app - this runs perfectly fine locally (in docker) and in Azure Functions app - in 2 digits ms response time. However once this is deployed in AWS this could be in mid 3digits ms response times.
I'm quite new to docker - what could I try to get down to 2digit ms response time in AWS

Comment: To get to a better response time, start with *not* using a Docker.  Remember that you may be getting double digit response times but does that include the spin up of the container each time?  Also, can you put the giant index (yes, 140MB is huge for a Lambda) into something like EFS so that the container doesn't have it but all Lambda's can access it?

Comment: I could try that- I naturally assumed the "closer" the data is to where the execution happens the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion by @stdunbar was indeed helpful. Once I mounted an EFS volume to the container the performance returned to what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If your dependencies support it, consider publishing your App using [AOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net8plus%2Cwindows). This removes the need for your code to get JITed each time, which can improve responsiveness especially on the frequent cold starts when you scale to 0.

If full AOT isn't on option, consider [Ready To Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run) which can reduce the need to JIT your code on initialization (but allows for tiered compilation to use JIT later if desired)